# pthread_singal awakes more than one thread on a multiprocessor system

Tags: pthreads

This is an excerpt from pthread_cond_wait man page
Some implementations, particularly on a multi-processor, may sometimes cause multiple threads to wake up when the condition variable is signaled simultaneously on different processors.

> In general, whenever a condition wait
>   returns, the thread has to re-evaluate
>   the **predicate** associated with the
>   condition wait to determine whether it
>   can safely proceed, should wait again,
>   or should declare a timeout. My
>   Question: here what is the meaning of
>   predicate?Does it mean that I need to
>   create one more variable apart from
>   the conditional variable provided in
>   **pthread_cond_wait** or does it referring to the same variable which
>   has been provided in 
>   **pthread_cond_wait**

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need an additional variable like `int done_flag;` to use like this:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
while (!done_flag) pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex);
/* do something that needs the lock held */
pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
/* do some other stuff that doesn't need the lock held */
```

Of course it often might not be a flag but rather a count, or some other type of variable, with a more complicated condition to test.

Answer (score 1):

This might be useful.  You can use pthread_kill to wake a particular thread.

```
sigset_t _fSigMask; // global sigmask
```

We do this before creating our threads.  Threads inherit their mask from the thread that creates them.  We use SIGUSR1 to signal our threads.  Other signals are available.

```
sigemptyset(&_fSigMask);
sigaddset(&_fSigMask, SIGUSR1);
sigaddset(&_fSigMask, SIGSEGV);
```

Then to sleep a thread

```
int nSig;
sigwait(&fSigMask, &nSig);
```

Then to wake the thread, YourThread.

```
pthread_kill(YourThread, SIGUSR1);
```

By the way, during our testing, sleeping and waking our threads this way was about 40x faster than using condition variables.